# Must the color of the Chuppah cloth be white?

Tags: color, chupah

I've only seen white cloth Chuppahs. Is there a limitation to what kind of cloths and colors can be used for a Chuppah?

Comment: I have seen non white

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Consider taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the site. Perhaps these [135 questions about weddings would interest you](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wedding).

Answer (score 1):

Besides having seen non-white, I have also seen one in which the names of the chasan and kallah (for all the children and grandchildren) were embroidered onto panels of a family chupah as each one got married. ?I was told that this was a German minhag (or at least for this family).